# SQL Query for Joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, join, view

I have 2 tables here with following structure Table1 which contains the Estimated cost and Table2 which contains the Actual cost and Task field in the Table2 is a foreign key based on the Table1 Budget 
Task field, i need to write a query and view to get the following result table which provides me the sum of Estimated_Cost and sum of Actual_cost details of the category.

Table1:

```
+------+----------+----------------+
| Task | Category | Estimated_Cost |
+------+----------+----------------+
|    1 |     9100 |         100.00 |
|    2 |     9100 |          15.00 |
|    3 |     9100 |           6.00 |
|    4 |     9200 |           8.00 |
|    5 |     9200 |          11.00 |
+------+----------+----------------+
```

Table2:

```
+---------+------+-------------+
| Voucher | Task | Actual_Cost |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 |    1 |       10.00 |
|       2 |    1 |       20.00 |
|       3 |    1 |       15.00 |
|       4 |    2 |       32.00 |
|       5 |    4 |        8.00 |
|       6 |    5 |        3.00 |
|       7 |    5 |        4.00 |
+---------+------+-------------+
```

Result table:

```
+----------+----------------+-------------+
| Category | Estimated_Cost | Actual_Cost |
+----------+----------------+-------------+
|     9100 |         121.00 |       77.00 |
|     9200 |          19.00 |       15.00 |
+----------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: hey @Ram Prasad, Please see below one with my name

Comment: Hey Ram Prasad, let me know your response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cat as Category,SUM(ecost) as Estimated_Cost,SUM(acost) as Actual_Cost from (SELECT table1.Estimated_Cost as ecost,table1.Category as cat,table2.Task,SUM(table2.Actual_Cost) as acost FROM `table2` join table1 ON
table2.Task = table1.task
GROUP by table2.Task)
as t11 
GROUP by cat
```

Comment: @Ram Prasad , did you check above query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **left join on table 1 and table 2 on task column**, and with help of **group by clause, calculate the sum of cost based on categories**. Below is the query

Just single query will help you achieve the goal.

```
select Category,sum(distinct(Estimated_Cost)),sum(Actual_Cost)
from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2
on t1.task = t2.task
groupd by t1.Category
```

Just wondering even if task is not part of table 2, should we still show sum in estimated cost?

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work because you're multiplying estimated costs with the number of rows in Table2 with the same id

Comment: This won't work because Estimated_cost values will go wrong due to the duplicate values of category..

Comment: Yeah, understood, just thinking, since task 3 in table 1 is not used in table 2, should it be also add up in estimated cost?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use two `group by` sql commands and then join them according to the `category`

```
select te.category, sum_estimated_cost, sum_actual_cost
from (
    select 
    select category,
           sum(Estimated_Cost) sum_estimated_cost
    from Table1 t1
    group by t1.category 
) te
join
(
    select category, 
           sum(Actual_Cost) sum_actual_cost
    from Table1 t1, Table2 t1
    where t1.task = t2.task
    groupy by t1.category 
) ta on te.category = ta.category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
select x.Category Category, y.Estimated_Cost Estimated_Cost, x.Actual_Cost Actual_Cost 
from
(
  select t1.Category Category, sum(a.Actual_Cost) Actual_Cost
  from Actuals a,
  (select distinct Category from Budget) t1
  where a.Task IN (Select Task from Budget where Category = t1.Category)
  group by t1.Category
) x,
(
  select Category, sum(Estimated_Cost) Estimated_Cost
  from Budget
  group by Category
) y
where x.Category = y.Category;
```

**Illustration with provided data:**

```
select * from Budget;
+------+----------+----------------+
| Task | Category | Estimated_Cost |
+------+----------+----------------+
|    1 |     9100 |         100.00 |
|    2 |     9100 |          15.00 |
|    3 |     9100 |           6.00 |
|    4 |     9200 |           8.00 |
|    5 |     9200 |          11.00 |
+------+----------+----------------+

select * from Actuals;
+---------+------+-------------+
| Voucher | Task | Actual_Cost |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 |    1 |       10.00 |
|       2 |    1 |       20.00 |
|       3 |    1 |       15.00 |
|       4 |    2 |       32.00 |
|       5 |    4 |        8.00 |
|       6 |    5 |        3.00 |
|       7 |    5 |        4.00 |
+---------+------+-------------+
 select x.Category Category, y.Estimated_Cost Estimated_Cost, x.Actual_Cost Actual_Cost
  -> from
  -> (
  ->   select t1.Category Category, sum(a.Actual_Cost) Actual_Cost
  ->   from Actuals a,
  ->   (select distinct Category from Budget) t1
  ->   where a.Task IN (Select Task from Budget where Category = t1.Category)
  ->   group by t1.Category
  -> ) x,
  -> (
  ->   select Category, sum(Estimated_Cost) Estimated_Cost
  ->   from Budget
  ->   group by Category
  -> ) y
  -> where x.Category = y.Category;
+----------+----------------+-------------+
| Category | Estimated_Cost | Actual_Cost |
+----------+----------------+-------------+
|     9100 |         121.00 |       77.00 |
|     9200 |          19.00 |       15.00 |
+----------+----------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select at1.Category, at1.Estimated_Cost, at2.Actual_Cost from (
select t1.Category, sum(t1.Estimated_Cost) as Estimated_Cost from Table1 t1
group by t1.Category) at1
left join (
select t1.Category, sum(t2.Actual_Cost) as Actual_Cost from Table2 t2 join Table1 t1 on t2.Task = t1.Task
group by t1.Category) at2
on at1.Category = at2.Category
```